# Assistance with SQL query returning not matched cells

Tags: mysql, sql, database, oracle11g

I have below 2 tables:

**Table1**

```
[schoolName] [Track] [Student Name] [Program ID]   
ABC          103     joe            1
ABC          101     Edward         2
QWE          103     Adam           5
QWE          103     Ben            1
```

**Table 2**

```
[SchoolName] [Program ID] [Class ID] [Class Name]
ABC          1            1          Science
ABC          1            2          Math
ABC          1            3          History
ABC          2            1          Science
QWE          5            1          Science
QWE          5            2          Math
QWE          1            2          Math
```

Looking to select student names attending track# 103 programs not covering class# 3 and return NULL for their class name, like below result:

```
[schoolName] [Track] [Student Name] [Program ID] [Class Name]
QWE          103     Adam           5            NULL
QWE          103     Ben            1            NULL
```

Am trying below query but it doesn't work:

```
select Table1.[schoolName], Table1.[Track], Table1.[Student Name], Table1.[Program ID], Table2.[Class Name] 
from table1, table2 
where Table1.[schoolName]=Table2.[SchoolName] 
  and Table1.[Program ID]=Table2.[Program ID] 
  and Table1.[Track]=103
  and Table2.[Class ID] = 3 
   OR Table2.[Class ID] IS NULL
```

What I'm doing wrong here?

Comment: Where does `[Program Class]` come from in your query?

Comment: sorry its typo mistake, should be Table2.[Class ID]

Comment: Are you sure that it is not **`SQL SERVER`**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all I highly doubt that you are using `MySQL` or `Oracle`. Quoting with`[]` is SQL Server specific.

> Looking to select student names attending track# 103 programs not covering class# 3 and return NULL for their class name

You could first get all records from `table1` where `track` is 103 and use correlated subquery to eliminate rows where program contains `class id` = 3:

```
SELECT T1.[schoolName],
       T1.[Track],
       T1.[Student Name],
       T1.[Program ID],
       NULL AS [Class Name] 
FROM table1 T1
WHERE T1.[Track] = 103
  AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                  FROM table2 T2
                  WHERE T1.[SchoolName] = T2.[SchoolName]
                    AND T1.[Program ID] = T2.[Program ID]
                    AND T2.[Class ID] = 3);
```

<kbd>**[`LiveDemo`](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/442487)**</kbd>

Consider using column names without space, like `Program_ID, Class_ID` and so on.

Comment: Thanks, it works exactly the way i want without spaces and removing [ ] from columns name